# Talend and core java

Tags: java, talend

Hi i am using talend here with java. stuck at a situation.

```
String modCode <br>
for (productsline product: ProdUtil.getProdForProfile(attrs.dhdeProd.profileId))
{
modCode = product.productCode;
System.out.println("products are:" +modCode);
}
```

this piece of code prints 3 didd modcodes. which is expected. Now i need to use these modcodes in if components. 
M unable to do as it says 
local variable modcode may not have been initialised in if component.
How can i do it??

Comment: i understaqnd its a scope peoblem. but unable to do it

Answer (score 0):

Its all about SCOPE.

You need to move the `modCode`  declaration  outside of the if block.

[Read here  the JLS#14 specs on Blocks and Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html)

Comment: my if component has to have a complete condition such as

Comment: the if statement which m talking about, it is defined in completely different component

Comment: okay. The code which u see above is pretty much everything. so in the if component, i say, modCode.equals("wood") (which is one of the modcode which i ll get by running the above code) the the error what i get is ::  variable modcode may not have been initialised in if component

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the if block you want to include it in occurs either in or after the for loop. If the warning about initialization is in your IDE, you may want to explicitly set

```
String modCode = null;
```

or

```
String modCode = "";
```

Your for loop might not execute if the iterator has no entries. This is why you are getting the warning.

Comment: Thanks for your help. i did try that way